# Как парсить steam на русском?

Tags: python, steam

Как правильнее парсить страницу Steam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда задаёшь ссылку в get_html(), к концу ссылки добавляй /?l=russian
Пример:

```
data = get_link(get_html('https://store.steampowered.com/app/1151340/Fallout_76/?l=russian'))
```